# regular expression ^[A-Za-z ]+$

Tags: asp.net, regex

^[A-Za-z ]+$ this expression working but it is not accepting single space i want to accept one space like 'data base'. ^[A-Za-z ]+$ this expression not taking space it taking like
'database' i want 'data base' like this help me. thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be look like

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z ]+$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
^[A-Za-z ]+$
```

As if you will see in the expression , there is space after small z, and this would allow space

Comment: Its confirmed as I have checked in my machine

Comment: Isn't this the same regex as in the question?

Comment: If you have multiple consecutive spaces, your solution will catch that as well, but that is perhaps ok with you.

Answer (score 3):

Even if what you had worked as you wanted, it will also match "d a t a b a s e". If you want it to match one space that might (or might not) be in the word, use something like `^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)?$`

Answer (score 0):

white space is represented by \s in Regex. Therefore you would want ^[a-zA-Z\s]+$

Comment: No. \s is an an character class which matches [\f\n\r\t\v\x85\p{Z}], so it can take other chars than space.